# Hide multiple DIV ID elements using Javascript If url has specific text (Already have code that hides one)

Tags: javascript

I have this script I often use, but I always add it to the code multiple times to hide multiple different things, which bad I believe. How can I add multiple IDs to it so I can hide multiple things

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = window.location.href;
  var msg = document.getElementById('thisid');
  // Check if URL contains the keyword
  if( url.search( 'thisword' ) > 0 ) {
      msg.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

For example where it says "thisid", how do I add another ID within this same code

And also, if possible how can I add another style? I'd like to also have visibility = "hidden"; added as well.

Please, and thank you so much for having read this and helping

Edited for Chris help:

```
  var url = window.location.href;
  var msg = document.getElementById('thisid');
  // Check if URL contains the keyword
if( url.search( 'thisword' ) > 0 ) {

const idList = ['something', 'something-else', 'another-thing', 'yet-another'];

idList.forEach((id) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element != null) {
    element.style.borderColor = 'green';
  element.style.display = 'none';
  element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
    console.warn(`An ID was specified for an element that was not found - ${element}`);
}
});
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use `document.querySelectorAll()` and then loop over that to hide the item(s): `var msgs = document.querySelectorAll('#thisid, #anotherID, #yetAnotherID');`

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen this reply, thank you for this I'll try this out!

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify you're going by unique ID's here's one way to just feed it an array of the desired ID's and do whatever to each instance. In the case an ID is incorrect, or not found we give a warning. I used `borderColor` for the example, but can easily change it to `display = "none"` or whatever. Cheers and next time, perhaps make an attempt on your own first then come back when you're stuck. :)

```js
const idList = ['something', 'something-else', 'another-thing', 'yet-another'];

idList.forEach((id) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element != null) {
    element.style.borderColor = 'green';
  } else {
    console.warn(`An ID was specified for an element that was not found - ${element}`);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: 20px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="something"></div>
  <div id="something-else"></div>
  <div id="not-a-thing"></div>
  <div id="another-thing"></div>
  <div id="yet-another"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I did attempt to, but what I tried wasn't working, I don't have much knowledge there. The code you gave, does it still work with the URL search portion I mentioned? I'm trying to hide things based on if the URL includes text, in the example I gave it hides the ID if the url cotains the text "thisword". And for the bordercolor example I knew how to change that, what I meant was if I can add an extra style, for example, both .bordercolor and .padding .display, is is possible to add those three in to that one code?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Would you like to compare your snippet to mine and maybe take a try at figuring out how? I'll give you a hint: Your `url` var could be added, your existing `if` statement arg could wrap my snippet to satisfy its condition before the next procedure of getting the elements and applying the changes. Stackoverflow is for folks looking to learn, not a free code service. Give it a go and if you get stuck we can take a look at your attempt and get you fixed up. :)

Comment: I understand, I've edited my original post since the code I have is too large to post here, please view the edited and let me know, I tried my best I apologize.